# Add relationship to node view

Tags: 8, views

I recently installed the "simplenews" and "simplenews_scheduler" modules. The first module generates a view where you can see the newsletters.

My idea was to create a relationship in that view to gather the data from the "simplenews_scheduler" table to know if a newsletter has an active schedule.

[image]

I tried the "views_data" and "views_data_alter" hooks but I can't add the "activated" field of the "simplenews_scheduler" table. **The base table of the view is "node_field_data"**

[image]

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? And if so, can someone tell me what I should do?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To create a view from a database table instead of using ***hook_views_data*** you can use [`Views Custom Table`](https://www.drupal.org/project/view_custom_table) module:

> View custom table module provide you functionality to integrate your custom table data to views, and access all it's column in views. This module use hook_view_data to add custom tables in views.

it's easy just follow the 7 steps in **How to use** section in module page.

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but I was trying to avoid use it due to the low usage statistics of the module

Comment: i have worked with it, it's good, it's stable and 1,603 site using it, what's the problem, besides the module just implement hook_views_data dynamically based on the config you set

Comment: I've tried it and it works fine, but that's not a decision that's up to me :/

Comment: in that case follow this tuto https://www.lullabot.com/articles/building-views-query-plugins-for-drupal-8-part-2 to create your own **Views Query Plugin** !